# Why can't I replace hyperlink content with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I cant change the `href` content with jQuery. Could anyone tell me whats wrong with the way I'm doing it. And I totally imported a jQuery js lib in my script section.

My jQuery:

```
 var link = jQuery('#link'); 
 link.attr("href", "http://www.amazon.com");
```

My HTML link:

```
<a id="link" href="https://www.google.com "  target="_blank" > website</a>
```

Comment: it works for me, did you import the correct jQuery version?

Comment: I imported this "  jquery-3.3.1.min.js  " . Actually I have already  implemented some function with other html element succeefully  . It just doesn't  work when I try to place a  hyperlink .

Comment: can u show me your complete script

Comment: Your code seems correct, but inspectors in browsers does not update, if that is what you are using to check.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/web3.min0_2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/bip39.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/ethereumjs-all-2018-1-17.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/hdkey.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/keythereum.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >

  Complete script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works. There is no problem with your code.

```js
 var link = jQuery('#link'); 
  link.attr("href", "http://www.amazon.com");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a
 id = "link" href = "https://www.google.com "  target="_blank" > website 
</a>
```

Comment: OKKK... That  solved out .I just add jQuery module in script of head section ! So thanks guys . Just a mistake !